# Epson Tm-M30II starts print not from the left side of paper

Tags: epson

I recently updated firmware of Epson Tm-M30II receipt printer using an app named epos2 printer, after that every print that I get doesn't starts from the left most side of paper but after 1 inch gap, and because of that, 80mm receipt print can't be fully printed.

I tried to reach their support team, their contact form has bug too and says "category" can not be selected, they have prepared a form to fix the hardware bug that has bug too :(

https://epson.custhelp.com/app/ask/p_model_name/Epson%20TM-m30%20Series

Their Star TM Utility also crashes on Android device.

Any Advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing  factory reset did not solve my issue by using the reset pin in the back of printer.

After reading the user manual here:

```
 https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/pos/bulk/tm-m30_trg_en_revh.pdf
```

and following these three steps, I did " Restore Default Values".

Turn off the printer and close the roll paper cover.
2 If the bottom cover is attached, remove the cover.
See "Removing the Covers" on page 85 for details on removing the bottom cover.
3 Hold down the status sheet button while turning on the printer.
A message is printed indicating that resetting is being performed, and the printer restarts.